# close div tag after 4 entries - mysql loop

Tags: php, mysql, html

i want my script to add a closing div tag after every fourth entrie of the db. i tried something like this:

```
<div class="row">
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM pages Where city = '1';");

while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {


echo "<div class=\"col-sm-4 col-md-3\">
echo "<h3>".$zeile['name']."</h3>";
..
echo "</div>";

$i=0;
i++;
if ($i == 4){
echo "</div>";}

}
?>
```

would be great if you can help me here. thx

Comment: "every fourth entries" you should use `if ($i % 4 == 0)` instead

Comment: Just to clarify the response of others, it's the modulus operator you are looking to use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: `Since, you are using 0 based indexing`, "every fourth entries" you should use **`if ($i % 3 == 0)`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Get names of all cities

2) Initiate an indexing variable

3) Ieterate through the loop

4) Open `<div class="row">` when $i==0 (Very First time) OR $i%4==0 (When fifth entry is to be printed). (Remember you are using 0 based indexing i.e. initializing $i=0).

5) Close the div tag for `<div class="row">` when fourth city name has been printed i.e. $i%3==0 (Remember you are using 0 based indexing i.e. initializing $i=0).

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php

    $ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM pages Where city = '1';");

    $i=0;

    while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {   

        if ($i == 0 || $i%4==0){ // <div class="row"> opens on first entry and every fifth entry
            echo "<div class=\"row\">"; 
        }

        echo "<div class=\"col-sm-4 col-md-3\">";
        echo "<h3>".$zeile['name']."</h3>";
        /*
            Rest of your code
        */
        echo "</div>";

        $i++;
        if ($i % 3 == 0){
            echo "</div>"; // <div class="row"> closes here on every fourth entry
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: damn i forgot that i have to open it aswell every 4th time it runs. can i just set the same with 0 at the start of the while loop?

Comment: No man, you cant, its simple logic. If you put $i=0 at the start of the loop, then every time $i=0. So, how will you track, if this is the fourth entry, because every time $i will equal 0. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
<div class="row">
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM pages Where city = '1';");

$i=0;  
while($zeile = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {
      echo "<div class=\"col-sm-4 col-md-3\">
      echo "<h3>".$zeile['name']."</h3>";
      ..
      echo "</div>";

     $i++;
     if ($i == 4){
          echo "</div>";
          $i = 0;
     }
}
?>
```